# Change sys.path upon execfile

Tags: python, path, python-import

I'm setting up Travis-CI for my GitHub repository, and upon creating the tests, I realised I have run into an issue.

My file-structure is as so:

```
parent-dir:
    src:
        prog.py
        generator.py
    test:
        test.py
```

Travis is set to run the test.py file, and in turn it executes the following command:

```
variables = {'help': '-h'}
execfile(sys.path[0] + "/../src/prog.py", variables)
```

This works fine as expected. However the issue is, `prog.py` imports `generator.py` as:

```
from generator import generate, languages
```

When I run the test, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named generator`.
I did some snooping around and found out that `sys.path[0]` did not update when I executed the second file.

My question is, is there a way to get the path to update upon execution of another file, or an even better way to simply get the location of the module being acted upon?

My code is as follows:

**test.py**

```
import os
import unittest2

import tests # Self reference for working directory.
relative_dir = os.path.dirname(tests.__file__)

class Test(unittest2.TestCase):
    def test_program(self):
        msg('Attempting to generate example utility.') # just prints the message, nothing interesting
        variables = {'help': '-h'} # command line variables
        execfile(relative_dir + "/../src/prog.py", variables)
```

**prog.py**

```
import os

import prog # This file.
relative_dir = os.path.dirname(dash_h.__file__)
```

I wont bother showing `generator.py`, because this is as complete as needs be. Regardless of generator, even just simply importing `prog` from itself will throw the exact same error.

```
ImportError: No module named prog
```

I am executing the following command in my terminal from the parent-dir directory:

```
python -B test/test.py
```

If the latter exists, I'd actually like to incorporate this into all other files I have.

Comment: What is your purpose here? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using `unittest2` to test the file in another folder. But I don't want to simply run a function, I want to execute it with arguments as if it was being executed from a command-line.

Comment: If you execute the same command from the same directory, does it work?

Comment: @finnrayment please provide a minimal, complete example. This should not be your entire code. In fact, in this case, you should just make up a very contrived example to show what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hmm... Seems not. Same issue persists.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Alright, will put the entire function in now.

Comment: @finnrayment Please read my previous comment again and see the help section for tips about creating a MCVE.

Comment: @AndrasDeak So why doesn't `import tests` do the same thing?

Comment: Why do you `import prog` in prog.py?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Take a look at the `relative_dir` variable. I want to be able to run my program from any folder on my computer. That variable will allow me to selectively choose a file relative to the module, not the current working directory of my terminal.

Comment: @finnrayment how does prog.py use this variable?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `open(relative_dir + '/usage.txt', 'r').readlines()`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think that's just a copy-paste error , `dash_h` is probably the real name of `prog`. Similarly `test` vs `tests`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Woops. It sure is. No reason to hide it, I just keep changing the name of the program all the time as I keep changing my mind. Just wanted to simplify it.

Comment: @finnrayment perhaps you should send the entire path to the input file rather than the folder which contains it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What are you thinking of? I don't think I could do it with arguments, because I already need them for parsing. (Its a command-line utility so **every** argument is checked)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to pass the path to the input file as a command line argument.

Comment: Hmmm.... Thats where the issue lies. I can't rely on `tests.py` to parse arguments to it, because **every** argument must be parsed on program execution.

Comment: @finnrayment tests.py should not accept any arguments to parse. Are there other args already required by the app under testing?

Comment: That is correct. `tests.py` is just run directly. The app itself is a command-line utility and it cycles through all arguments received. I want to test this functionality by providing it with data to parse. This is why I cannot parse the path to it, because *by design*, it will attempt to make sense out of the path and end up storing it in a variable I don't want it to.